# Как вставить данные в несколько таблиц MYSQL phpadmin через PHP?

Tags: php, html

Столкнулся с проблемой. Имеются несколько таблиц department (id, discription), employee (id, first_name, last_name), person (passport_id, serial, number).
Как сделать запрос чтобы через Insert сразу в несколько таблиц шла вставка?

вот мой пример, но ко второй таблице employee не вставляются данные , только айди увеличивается в таблице department, хотя указаны и переменные и сама таблица конкретная.

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$discription = $_POST['discription'];

// Create Department

if (isset($_POST['add']))  {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO department (`discription`)
    VALUES ('".$discription."')";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    if($query){
        header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
}


// Create1 Employee

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];


if (isset($_POST['add']))  {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO employee (`first_name`, `last_name`)
    VALUES ('".$first_name."','".$last_name."')";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    if($query){
        header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
}
```

Кто сможет подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: MySQL не поддерживает вставку в несколько таблиц сразу. Используйте хранимую процедуру.

Comment: Что вам мешает данные вставить последовательно, обернув в транзакцию? У вас после вставки данных в первую таблицу идёт перенаправление и код завершает свою работу.

Comment: у вас же редирект стоит после добавления в первую таблицу (`header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])`) 
соотвественно, выполнение последующей части скрипта не выполняется. Вынесите редирект за `if`'ы (добавьте для него отдельный) и должно заработать

Answer (score 0):

Если это учебный пример, то проблема в том, что после первой вставки происходит `header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` и дальше операции не идут.

Пробуйте такой код:

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$discription = $_POST['discription'];

if (isset($_POST['add']))  {
    // Create Department
    $sql = "INSERT INTO department (`discription`)
    VALUES ('".$discription."')";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    if($query){
       // header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }

   $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
   $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];

   $sql_2 = "INSERT INTO employee (`first_name`, `last_name`)
   VALUES ('".$first_name."','".$last_name."')";
    $query_2 = $conn->query($sql_2);
    if($query_2){
        header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
}
```

НО! повторюсь это очень "грязный" код!!